# What are these numbers that convert to text?

Tags: c, ascii

```
/***
 * Author: Omar IRAQI
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 11

int main(void) {
    int i, *p, encoded_message[] = {1634558290, 544104804, 1701994827, 539782501, 1918985572, 
                                1970565920, 1953391972, 1226845811, 1936289056, 1870209139, 8565};
    char *message;

    printf("%s\n", (char*)encoded_message);

    /**
     * Let's say it again!
     */
    message = (char*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    p = (int*)message;

    for (i=0; i < N; i++, p++)
        *p = encoded_message[i];

    printf("%s\n", message);
    return 0;
}
```

this outputs the message twice:
Ramadan Kareem, dear students. I miss you!

I was wondering what these encoded numbers are since they don't match with ASCII code

Comment: They do match ASCII

Comment: Oh, how so? I thought the ASCII for a text would be just the code for each character next to each other.

Comment: It is, 8 bits at a time. Look at those numbers in hex. Also lookup "endianness".

Comment: Oh ok, thank you! I'll look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each int should be split into 4 bytes to recover the individual ascii codes. You could simply print each int as hex.

You can also calculate:

```
1634558290 % 256
(1634558290 >> 8) % 256
(1634558290 >> 16) % 256
```

and so on.

You have 11 x 4 byte integers for a total of 44 bytes. This corresponds closely to the length of the message.

```
1 634 558 290 = 0x616D6152
52 : R
61 : a
6D : m
61 : a
```

Lookup little endian vs big endian for why the bytes are inverted.

Comment: @DavidRanieri, absolutely!